# Create fields with certain placeholders in a row

Tags: javascript, dom

With the help of the comunity (Thanks all of you !) I manage to create 3 fields at a time in a single row, anytime the user needs it. The thing is that everytime it create the fields, the placeholder is always "Another field". I would like that instead of that says **Infrastracture, Time, Monthly Cost"**, but I have no clue how to do that.

Thank you Kindly !

Html Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Awsome Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!-- My Title-->
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
      
      <form class="Form" id="formulario">
          <h1>Factibilidad Técnica y Operativa</h1>
          <h2>Análisis de Infraestructura</h2>

          <!-- Campos en Columnas-->
        <div class="container" id="contenedor">
            <div class="row" id="campo">

              <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Infraestructura">
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tiempo">
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Costo Mensual">
              </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
          <!-- Iconos de Agregar / Eliminar Campos-->
          <div class="Controls">
            <a href="#" id="add_more_fields" onclick="createTwoInput()"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Añadir</a>
            <a href="#" id="removefields" onclick="Eliminar()"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>Eliminar</a>
          </div>

      </form>
          <!-- JS Script-->    
          <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var survey_options = document.getElementById('campo');
var add_more_fields = document.getElementById('add_more_fields');
var remove_fields = document.getElementById('remove_fields');

function Añadir(){
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'col-lg-4 mb-2')

    var newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.setAttribute('type','text');
    newField.setAttribute('class','form-control');
    newField.setAttribute('placeholder','Another Field');
    survey_options.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.appendChild(newField);
 
}

function createTwoInput(){
  Añadir();
  Añadir(); 
  Añadir();  
}


function Eliminar(){
    var input_tags = survey_options.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if(input_tags.length > 2) {
        survey_options.removeChild(input_tags[(input_tags.length) - 1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function that can add or remove a `.row` depending on exactly whitch button was clicked.

### [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

1. Register the 'click' event to an element that contains all of the elements you need to listen for events on. This element (ex. `<form id='infra'>`) is called the *listener* and once the event (ex. `'click'`) triggers, the event handler (ex. `addRem()`) will run.

   ```
   const ui = document.forms.infra;
   ui.onclick = addRem;
   ```
2. The event handler `addRem(event)` passes the Event Object (ex. (`event`)) which has a property that helps determine what the user clicked called `.target`.

   ```
   const clicked = event.target;
   if (clicked.matches('#add')) {...}
   else if (clicked.matches('#rem')) {...}
   else {...}
   ```
3. When `'button#add'` is clicked, instead of writing a line of code for each and every attribute, element, etc. create a `htmlString` that represents everything that needs to be rendered. In `addRem()` it's `row` variable which is rendered into real HTML by [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method.

   ```
   const row = `<section class='row'>`Everything within`</section>`;
   main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', row);
   ```
4. When `'button#rem'` is clicked, it removes the last `.row` unless there's only one left.

   ```
   let rows = main.querySelectorAll('.row');
   ...&& rows.length > 1) {
   rows[rows.length-1].remove();
   ```

### Example 1

```js
const ui = document.forms.infra;
const io = ui.elements;

ui.onclick = addRem;

function addRem(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;
  const main = document.querySelector('.container');
  let rows = main.querySelectorAll('.row');
  
  if (clicked.matches('#add')) {
    const row = ` <section class="row"> <hr> <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2"> <input name='infs' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Infraestructura"> </div> <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2"> <input name='time' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Tiempo"> </div> <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2"> <input name='cost' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Costo Mensual"> </div> <hr> </section>`;
    main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', row);
  } else if (clicked.matches('#rem') && rows.length > 1) {
    rows[rows.length-1].remove();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

```css
.btn-group {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form class="form" id="infra">
    <h1>Factibilidad Técnica y Operativa</h1>
    <h2>Análisis de Infraestructura</h2>

    <main class="container">
      <section class="row">
        <hr>
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='infs' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Infraestructura">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='time' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Tiempo">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='cost' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Costo Mensual">
        </div>
        <hr>
      </section>
    </main>

    <nav class="btn-group">
      <button id='add' class='btn btn-success' type='button'>
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Añadir
      </button>
      <button id='rem' class='btn btn-danger' type='button'>
        <i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i> Eliminar
      </button>
    </nav>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

### Example 2

Variation of adding `.row` using `.cloneNode()`

```js
const ui = document.forms.infra;
const io = ui.elements;

ui.onclick = addRem;

function addRem(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;
  const main = document.querySelector('.container');
  let rows = main.querySelectorAll('.row');
  
  if (clicked.matches('#add')) {
    let row = rows[0].cloneNode(true);
    let inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
    inputs.forEach(input => input.value = '');
    main.appendChild(row);
  } else if (clicked.matches('#rem') && rows.length > 1) {
    rows[rows.length-1].remove();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

```css
.btn-group {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form class="form" id="infra">
    <h1>Factibilidad Técnica y Operativa</h1>
    <h2>Análisis de Infraestructura</h2>

    <main class="container">
      <section class="row">
        <hr>
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='infs' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Infraestructura">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='time' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Tiempo">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='cost' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Costo Mensual">
        </div>
        <hr>
      </section>
    </main>

    <nav class="btn-group">
      <button id='add' class='btn btn-success' type='button'>
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Añadir
      </button>
      <button id='rem' class='btn btn-danger' type='button'>
        <i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i> Eliminar
      </button>
    </nav>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One options is to pass into your function the number of items you want to create, and pull the placeholder from an array, like this:

```js
let survey_options = document.querySelector('.survey_options')

function Añadir(num_create) {
  let placeholders = ["Infrastracture", "Time", "Monthly Cost"];
  for (let x = 0; x < num_create; x++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'col-lg-4 mb-2')

    var newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    newField.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
    newField.setAttribute('placeholder', placeholders[x]);
    survey_options.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.appendChild(newField);
  }

}

Añadir(3);
```

```html
<div class='survey_options'></div>
```

Comment: I think I'm doing sth wrong, I tried that solution but it only shows 'placeholder[x]'. It also my IDE is saying 'Placeholders' isn't being used, whitch is weird because it is being used as attribute. I think the issue comes from how javascript list, but I don't know how it behaves, I'm very very new in javascript

Comment: No, i had a typo in my code. So sorry, I updated and fixed, and made it a snippet so you can test it right here

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much for you patience and your time for the response !